# C tokenizing the input from stdin

Tags: c, strtok

I am work in parsing the commands that we get from stdin. My code nearly works. It prints all tokens except the first token.  below is my code

```
            /* Read a command line */
            if (!fgets(line, 1024, stdin))
                return 0;

            char *p = strtok (line, " \n");
            while (p != NULL)
            {
                Array[tokenscounter++]  = p;
                p = strtok (NULL, " \n");

            }




  }
  return 0;
}
```

when i print all tokens stored in an array, it does not print the first one. any reason why is it behaving like that?

Comment: Probably not your problem, but I don't think `fflush(NULL)` does anything.

Comment: @John3136 I have updated the question.

Comment: @SteveSummit even after fflush(NULL); does not change anything.

Comment: Your program works properly for me (after I fill in a few missing details).  So I suspect the code you're showing us is not the code you're running, meaning that the problem is in something we can't see.

Comment: Is there supposed to be a comment prefix before `tokencounter`?

Comment: You would have the problem you describe if you switched the order of `Array[i++] = p;` and `p = strtok(NULL, " \n");`

Comment: @Barmar I am not sure, do you mean ++tokencounter?

Comment: I mean it should probably be `int i = 0; // token counter`

Comment: @Barmar yeah you are right. supposed to be a comment.

Comment: Is it possible for you to copy and paste, all at once, *exactly* the code you're running?  (All of it?)  That way we can debug *your* program, not the different program you've retyped here (which, incidentally, works).

Comment: [I cant reproduce](https://ideone.com/Vcim2y) using the code shown

Comment: What command line(s) are you typing as input to the program?

Comment: @SteveSummit for now i m typing hello world

Comment: @SteveSummit I have pasted all my code.

Comment: @user3121023  no. hello space world

Comment: The bug now reproduces for me.  So it must have something to do with your redirection logic.

Comment: @SteveSummit I think i figured out the bug. I was not checking if redirection is null. Thanks anyways

Comment: Please provide [**A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).